# Find the mass and the center of mass of a thin flat surface in the shape of a region .

Tags: integration, area

Find the mass and the center of mass of a thin flat surface in the
shape of a region  in the xy-plane that lines outside the circle ^2 + ^2 = 1 and inside the circle ^2 + ^2 = 2. The mass density  = 1/((^2+^2)^(1/2))
[Hint: consider any symmetry that may exist.]

PLEASE HELP I HAVE NO IDEA WHERE TO START. All I know is im supposed to use the center of mass equations with double integrals.

Comment: You might start by drawing the region.

Comment: It might also help to properly format your question with MathJaX

Comment: Actually, start by putting the second circle equation into standard form to identify its center and radius. Then follow amd's instruction, then do the thing you say you know you are supposed to do